# How to access performance object of every resource in a web page?

Tags: javascript, browser, web, pageload

I can see, in **Chrome Developer tools**, loading time, time it took to get a particular resource from server and other info, for all of the resources in a webpage.

I want to capture these stats using JavaScript. How is it possible?

there is window.performance object available, but only for the requested page, not for page resources.
Is there any way to access performance object of all of the page resources.

Comment: I think most of the performance information is kept in the background. I suggestion asking `Google` a little.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [`window.performance.getEntries()`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#about_the_resource_timing_api) to get resource-specific stats:

```
var resource = window.performance.getEntries()[0];

console.log(resource.entryType);  // "resource"
console.log(resource.duration);   // 39.00000000430737
console.log(resource.startTime);  // 218.0000000007567
```

Sample from the above link:

> [image]

Comment: I tried this but always get the following error

TypeError: Object #<Performance> has no method 'getEntries', I am using chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 and firefox 22.0

Comment: @user989512 The [related spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/) is still in flux and was changed in May. Chrome 28 appears to support it, though.

Comment: thanks Jonathan, I upgrade chrome to 28 and its working now :-)

Comment: Jonathan, hopefully you'll come back to this thread. What i want to know what EXACTLY does "duration" represent. The actual "load time" of the resource. It is not clear to me, as in your example above for getEntries()[0] - did that take 39ms to actually load?

Comment: If you want resources, you should use `getEntriesByType('resource')`, because other types are tracked (`render`, `composite`, `mark`, etc).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Hey! [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753673/perfomance-api-in-javascript-not-working-as-expected-in-vue-js) can you please take a look at this because this doesnt work on vue js

Answer (score 3):

There is still a bug in latest version of chrome - 29.0.1547.76 m
When you raise an xmlhttprequest, lets say while downloading an image, you can see that the resource is downloaded with status code 200 OK in network tab, but the performance.getEntries() or performance.getEntriesByName(resourceUrl) doesn't list the resource entry. When the page load is complete and you evaluate performance.getEntriesByName(resourceUrl) in console, it lists properly. So, there is a lag in chrome while populating the resource entries in performance entries?
In IE10, this works perfectly fine.

Comment: Bug in chrome seems fixed now these days... :)

Answer (score 2):

window.performance.getEntries()
may return not all resources. after bufferful some records is disapear
need check it before it happend

---

head code part

```
var storedEntries = [];
var updateStoredEntries = p => {
  storedEntries.concat(
    p.getEntries().filter(rec => /yourRegExp/.test(rec.name))
  )
};
performance.addEventListener('resourcetimingbufferfull', e => {
  updateStoredEntries(e.target)
});
```

...
later part

```
updateStoredEntries(performance)
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082742/how-to-clear-chrome-performance-entries-or-bypass-the-limit-on-their-number though it appears it fires `resourcetimingbufferfull` without any access to the entry that just over filled it, so it is lost, and just keeps firing that event over and over as more come in and are dropped on the ground...