# How to clear chrome performance entries or bypass the limit on their number?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, firefox

I use Google Chrome to analyze the performance of some webpage that using Javascript dynamically load scripts and other resources.

I use the `performance.getEntries()` method, but I noticed that Chrome records only the first 150 resources. I could not find any way to get more entries, or to remove old entries.

I saw that the performance object has methods like `clearMeasures` or `clearMarks`, but I failed to use them for removing entries.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to get more than 150 performance entries? If possible - how?
2. Is it possible to clear the entries (for example, after reading the data of some entry, to remove it)? If possible - how?

Comment: Hi @Gari, did you find a solution for this? could you please help me?

Comment: @Jugi I came across this question only today. I know it is too late now. But check if this works for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
performance.webkitSetResourceTimingBufferSize(your_number);
```

For what it's worth, in Firefox, you can use

```
performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(your_number);
```

For full list of browsers and their support for `window.performance`, see http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/en/home?&property=performance

Comment: performance.webkitSetResourceTimingBufferSize seems to be not working. It throws error as it is not a function. Can anyone help me with the solution? i need to capture all the request that are more than 150

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `performance.getEntries()`, use `performance.getEnteriesByType('resource')` After measuring the timing with `performance.getEnteriesByType('resource')`, call `performance.clearResourceTimings()` right away. It will empty the buffer.

```
function measureTiming()
{
    var resourceTiming = performance.getEnteriesByType('resource');
    performance.clearResourceTimings();
}
```