# C# webbrowser get loaded resource(image/mp3) just like chrome NetWork

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Is that possible to get all resource URLs loaded by a page including the resource loaded through JavaScript programmatically by C# webbrowser.

Just the URLs like chrome "NetWork"

Answer (score 0):

One option is to read `window.performance.getEntries` object that contains all timing information - [How to access performance object of every resource in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691889/how-to-access-performance-object-of-every-resource-in-a-web-page) (you may need to also configure IE to run in latest mode instead of IE8 or whatever default is for WebBrowser control).

Another option is to configure browser to use proxy and point it to your own proxy (maybe the same process). This way you'll see all requests and will be able to measure or even modify them. You can use FiddlerCore as proxy implementation.

Comment: for option 1, do you mean control JavaScript in C# code?

Comment: @user2269250 You should be able to call it directly with C# or call helper JavaScript function - whatever you use to access objects inside browser.