# What does window.performance.getEntries() mean?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I thought that `window.performance.getEntries()` would match the number of requests according to Chromium's 'Network' tab, but that doesn't seem to be the case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfKtH.png. What am I missing?

[image: [screenshot showing mismatch]]

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: perhaps cached items aren't included? redirects?

Comment: If somebody finds a way how to get all the loaded resources (like in network tab of devTools), I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

If your page have multiple redirections, network tab shows everything whereas performance entiries shows only the resources from last/current document. Also the entries count doesn't include your HTML/document count where network counts that too.

I would also like to refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18978803's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case some Requests were missing, which occurred after the Page had finished loading.
The Networking Tab showed *all* Requests, but `window.performance.getEntries()` only Showed those who responded to the original Page Call (and not later actions on the Page). I believe `performance.getEntries()` and the [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API) only concern themselves with the original building of the Page.

Answer (score 1):

Only taking chrome into consideration here, but the number of entries is limited. You can extend the limit by executing:

```
window.performace.setResourceTimingBufferSize(9999);
```