# Is there any way in Puppeteer to get the exact data from the Chrome Network tab?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm attempting to use Puppeteer to navigate to a URL and extract the metrics from the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools. For example, navigating to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455964/what-does-window-performance-getentries-mean) shows the following Network info, and captures a total of 47 requests.
[image]

However, I'm trying to get these metrics using the following code:

```
import { Browser, Page } from "puppeteer";

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
    const browser: Browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null
    });

    const page: Page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455964/what-does-window-performance-getentries-mean");

    let performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
        await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.getEntries()))
    );

    console.log(performanceTiming);
}

run();
```

However, when I peer into the `performanceTiming` object, it only has 34 items in it:
[image]

Therefore, my questions are please:

1. Why is there a difference in the number of requests the Network tab vs `performance.getEntries()` are showing?
2. Is it possible to get `performance.getEntries()` to show all of the requests instead of only a portion of them?
3. Is it possible for Puppeteer to get all of the data from the Network tab?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [page.tracing](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagetracing) feature.

```
const browser =  await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.tracing.start({ categories: ['devtools.timeline'], path: "./tracing.json" });
await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455964/what-does-window-performance-getentries-mean");
var tracing = JSON.parse(await page.tracing.stop());
```

The `devtools.timeline` category has many things to explore.

You can get all the request filtering by `ResourceSendRequest`

```js
tracing.traceEvents.filter(te => te.name ==="ResourceSendRequest")
```

And all the response filtering by `ResourceReceiveResponse`

```js
tracing.traceEvents.filter(te => te.name ==="ResourceReceiveResponse")
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to tracing. However, when I look at each of objects within the `tracing` JSON, they don't provide the timing info I'm looking for, like DNS, connect, wait, load, response. Do you know how to get that data?

Comment: Maybe you can cook that data evaluating all the entries for the tracing. I think you won't get better data than that. But yeah, maybe it's too raw.

Comment: Yeah, cooking the data is at least worth investigating. I'm assuming I'd have to filter by other `traceEvents` names? Do you know where the documentation is for all of those names?

Comment: I think they don't have a static model. This is the official doc http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool/trace-event-reading

Comment: @aBlaze by any chance you able to get the DNS records?