# Perfomance Api In Javascript Not Working As Expected In Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am working on a small project in which I have to calculate the time taken by each page to load and to achieve that I am making use of [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API) and to be precise I am making use of [getEntriesByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByName) In Performance API like shown below.

```
performance.getEntriesByName(window.location.href)
```

Open the console by pressing **F12** on your keyboard and run the above line and see the result.

**RESULT**

```
connectEnd: 1.55999994603917
connectStart: 1.55999994603917
decodedBodySize: 132839
domComplete: 1405.1149999722838
domContentLoadedEventEnd: 887.4099999666214
domContentLoadedEventStart: 867.9899999988265
name: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
nextHopProtocol: "h2"
redirectCount: 0
....
```

So it is going to show some data regarding the page. As you can see the value of **name** is the page url. So running the above line on different pages will give us metrics of that specific page.

**ISSUE**

So the issue is that when i do that on any page in a **vue js project** it just gives the info for the main page. Let us say my main page is **/dashboard** and when I run that line of code in console on dashboard It gives me the metrics and runs fine but let us say I run that line on **/dashboard/users**. It returns an **EMPTY** array.

**NOTE**

Can anybody guess why that happens or can anybody tell me a different way by which we can get the **RESULT** values in any other way. (without using performance api of JS), like how can we get all these details without the use of performance api or any way to fix this thing

**CHECK THIS**

[Website made in vue js](http://frontenddeveloperlove.com/)

Go to this website and change routes on there and do the above procedure.Same thing is happening here too. Why is it happening in all vue js websites.

Answer (score 1):

The type of data you're trying to obtain via performance.getEntriesByName(window.location.href) is dependent on page load. Vuejs projects with Vue Router will do just one initial page load. No subsequent page loads will happen on route change. This will happen with any Single Page Application.

You can see this in your given example by going to a route of your choice, reloading the page and executing performance.getEntriesByName(window.location.href) again. You'll get your desired dataset instead of an empty array.

In general you would have to create some performance "marks" manually in your Vuejs app and then you could access the entries that you created from those marks.

Comment: An example would help.